# UIViewController called from Storyboard is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I am calling a view with method;

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:];
```

Yesterday, this method was working well, but after some time something happened, it has stopped working.

I am using both xCode6 beta 6 and xcode5 v5.1.1

My code is as below, here all objects of an ViewController is nil?

What is wrong with this?

```
(IBAction)addTemplateViewPressed:(id)sender
{

PhotoTemplateViewController *templateVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"photoTemplateViewController"];

//NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(templateVC.view.frame));

if(photoVerticalArray.count !=0 )
{
    photoVerticalArray = [templateVC setVerticalImages:photoVerticalArray];
}
else
{
    verticalFinished = true;
}

if(photoHorizontalArray.count !=0)
{
    photoHorizontalArray = [templateVC setHorizontalImages:photoHorizontalArray];
}
else
{
    horizontalFinished = true;

}

if(!verticalFinished && !horizontalFinished)
{
    CGRect temp = templateVC.mainView.frame;

    if(lastPosition == 0)
    {
        temp.origin.y = lastPosition = templateVC.mainView.frame.origin.y+48;
    }
    else
    {
        lastPosition = temp.origin.y= lastPosition + temp.size.height-4;
    }

    templateVC.view.frame = temp;
    [mainView addSubview:templateVC.view];


    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(mainScrollView.contentSize));
    [mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, temp.origin.y+temp.size.height+50)];
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(mainScrollView.contentSize));

}
```

Comment: this is your storyboard id : "photoTemplateViewController"

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes, i have checked it many times it is correct

Comment: [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]; Did this work for other controllers? Is it just 'PhotoTemplateViewController'?

Comment: Does "PhotoTemplateViewController *templateVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"photoTemplateViewController"];" return a non-nil value or not? If nil then you're not setting your storyboard id properly

Comment: @Wizkid it returns a non-nil value but, its properties are nil